# How to find leak, rain coming in from window frame

Tags: leak, siding, flashing

During heavy rain in Southern California some of my windows have been leaking from the upper edge of frame. I had someone come look at the top caulking and it had separated from exterior stucco so he re caulked, but four days later with new rain… same leak. Based on that he said to contact HOA because rain must be getting behind the caulk.
There are small cracks in stucco but were filled with clear sealant as bandaid in case that was issue. I’m concerned it was shoddy flashing or as my neighbor guessed, the windows were too small and the foam placed around them allows the windows to move about? HOA is adamant it shouldn’t be the stucco letting in water since the building is waterproofed wrapped. How do I determine where the leak is coming from so that I can take next steps myself or with HOA? Hire a contractor? Will they have to open up my walls or the stucco?

The windows aren’t recessed, they stick out about a half inch with no cap.

Windows installed in 2021- warranty on labor expired 2022
Windows themselves have lifetime guarantee 
I bought the unit in 2022

[image]

Comment: Down under, they would have what we call a flashing (perhaps cap is the same).  There is no substitute for it.  The windows are probably not faulty,

Comment: Is your HOA not responsible for maintaining the integrity of the external building envelope? If so, then it doesn't really matter (to you) what the actual root cause of the problem is - it's the HOA's responsibility to fix.